# Is it worth to check for value before assignment?

Tags: c#, .net

I usually use something like this:

```
if(!variable.Equals(value))
{
    variable = value;
}
```

I was learnt to do this but I am just wondering if it is worthy. What is cost of comparison vs assignment? I guess it is not, but is C# somehow optimised for operation of assignment of same data to the variable?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess the assignment is faster

Comment: @KaeL it is clear for properties, because of quite common implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged you don't want to fire unnecessary events, this question is slightly different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison operation is harder for CPU  and takes a little more time than assignment operation.

Only assignment will be faster than only comparison, but if the `variable` is not equal to `value` you will execute two operations - comparison and assignment - more time.

So, assignment without comparison will be executed faster even if `variable` is equal to `value`:

```
variable = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operation itself is very cheap (fast). Dereferencing the variable may be  expensive. For example, `product[a.f() + 3].age = 2;` would do a lot of calculation to reach the location of the desired `age`. In your case, you do the same dereferencing in your `if` condition. So, there is no advantage at all in testing before assigning. Comparison means "subtraction and check zero flag), and involves reading the value of the variable from the memory. Assignment means writing a value to memory. Reading and writing into memory are equivalent. In my knowledge, compilers do not use this optimization trick.

Answer (score -1):

It can by worthy only if value of `varible` is arleady `value` and you want to have super fast and optimized code. But in my opinion profit will be 
unnoticeable. You should use `variable = value;` and it will works fine and code will be more clear.